# how do i stop the ajax callback function from handling my res.redirect() response from the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ajax, redirect

I have a project, a simple login form hooked to nodejs which is connected to MongoDB as the database.
 
relevant to this question

- I use pure javascript, no jquery
- my main aim in this project is to display error in the form without reloading the page (through a model) but if the information is correct or a user is found, the user is **redirected to the profile page** => now this is where the problem is.

this is my client request

```
 // *the myModel is a bootstrap function that is used to notify users for error* 
 const myModel = new bootstrap.Modal(document.querySelector('.modal'), {
            focus : true
        })
        document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
          e.preventDefault()
          data = {
            username : document.forms[0].username.value,
            password : document.forms[0].password.value
          }
          fetch("/login", {
            method: "POST",
            headers : { "content-Type": "application/json" },
            body : JSON.stringify(data)
          }).then(async(response)=>{
            data = await response.json()
            if(data.err){
              console.log(data.redirect)
            document.querySelector(".modal-body").innerText = data.err
            myModel.show() 
            }else{
              window.location.replace(data.redirect)
            }
         
          })
          .catch(err=>{
            document.querySelector(".modal-body").innerText = err.message
            myModel.show()
          })
        })
```

this is my server-side code/response

```
.post(function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body)
    if(req.body.username.trim() && req.body.password.trim()){
        const data = req.body
        userCollection.findOne({username:data.username},function(error,back){
            if(error){
                console.log(error.message)
            }else{
                if(back){
                    console.log(back)
                    if(back.password === data.password){
                      res.redirect("/profile")
                    }else{
                        res.json({err : "password or username wrong, try again"})
                        res.end()
                    }

                }
                else{
                    console.log("no user found, check your inputs again")
                    res.json({err : "no user found, check your inputs again"})
                   res.end()
                 }
            }
        })

    }else{
        res.json({err:"username or password empty"})
    }
```

> everything works fine except when a user is found and the passwords match and I'm trying to redirect the user, the client-side request `.catch`  keeps sending me an error **"unexpected token < in json  at position 4"**
> but if I change the  `res.redirect` to maybe `res.json("your account has been found")` then it works fine without any error.

#### i've been stuck here for a day+ if you know how i will combat this, help for the sake of my mental health " haha

~~

Comment: Have you checked in the network tab of chrome devtools to see what the actual response is sent by the server to client?

Comment: ALSO! Change `res.redirect("/profile")` to `res.json({redirect : "/profile"})`

Comment: thank you @AbdulHaseeb  res.json({redirect: "/profile"}) worked for me, but how do I check for the response sent from the server in chrome or can you explain to me why the res.redirect didn't work

Comment: When you do `res.redirect` the response is redirected to another location instead of returning a response to your client. And your client is told that the response was redirected. What YOU needed was a success/no-success/error response respect to authentication being success/failure/errored and return that to the client. And let the client handle each type of response.

Comment: As for network tab, it is very helpful and you can see what data the browser is sending to the API and what API is sending you as a response, this might help you.
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/